# How can I carry out the "Save Link As" function with just one click on a link?

Tags: php, javascript, html

So, as most of you may know, when you put a link to a file on a webpage, you must right-click the link and click "save link as" to download the file. I wanted to know if there is a way to just be able to click the link and automatically download the file.

Comment: Search is miraculous... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Force+download

Answer (score 2):

There is a way, using `header()` calls to specify `Content-Disposition`.

For example, I have an image download script that looks like this:

```
header("Content-Type: $mime");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"foobar.baz\"");
readfile($filename);
```

You need to find out what the MIME type of the file is (and set it using `Content-Type: $mime`, tell the browser this file is an attachment using the `Content-Disposition` header, and then output the file with `readfile()`.

[This tutorial](http://www.higherpass.com/php/Tutorials/File-Download-Security/) has some more information on the matter.

Comment: thank you so much guys and sorry, im new to stack overflow, wasnt really sure where to start.